# jQuery Drag and Drop UI Limit Container Hover 1 IMG

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to build a basic drag and drop print friendly photo gallery. I want to allow users to take 10 photos, arrange them anyway they want, then print them out. The code below does the basic drag and drop putting the photos/img into a div, but I can not limit the div to only accept 1 photo.

How can I fix it so when the img hovers over a div with an image, it does not allow for drop. I tried the disable function, but if you uncomment it, when an item get dropped and moved again, nothing can go back to that spot. The enable function does not fix that.

Help please :(

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 0;
      $(".shirts").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
      $(".drop").droppable({
        accept: ".shirts",
        activeClass: 'droppable-active',
        hoverClass: 'droppable-hover',
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
              $(this).append(ui.draggable);     
    //          $(this).droppable('disable'); 
    //          $(this).droppable('enable'); 
            }
      });
    });
            </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        .drop{width:100px;min-height:109px;float:left;}
        .allshirts{width:100%;border:1px solid #eee;min-height:140px;}
        .shirts{float:left;width:100px;}
        .blanket{width:510px;min-height:140px;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
        .droppable-hover{background:#000;}
        .clear{clear:both;}
        </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="allshirts drop">
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb1_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb2_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb3_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb4_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb1_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb2_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb3_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb4_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb1_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb2_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb3_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb4_thumb.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="blanket">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <td><div id="photo1" class="drop"></div></td>
                <td><div id="photo2" class="drop"></div></td>
                <td><div id="photo3" class="drop"></div></td>
                <td><div id="photo4" class="drop"></div></td>
                <td><div id="photo5" class="drop"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="photo6" class="drop"></div></td>
                <td><div id="photo7" class="drop"></div></td>
                <td><div id="photo8" class="drop"></div></td>
                <td><div id="photo9" class="drop"></div></td>
                <td><div id="photo10" class="drop"></div></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Crude but simple:

I also assumed that you want to let them rearrange and override their choices. So I added cloning of the original element.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 0;
      $(".shirts").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
      $(".drop").droppable({
        accept: ".shirts",
        activeClass: 'droppable-active',
        hoverClass: 'droppable-hover',
                drop: function(ev, ui) {
        if ($(this).html() == ""){
                  $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());         
        }else{
           $(this).empty().append($(ui.draggable).clone());
        }
                }
      });
    });
                </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        .drop{width:100px;min-height:109px;float:left;}
        .allshirts{width:100%;border:1px solid #eee;min-height:140px;}
        .shirts{float:left;width:100px;}
        .blanket{width:510px;min-height:140px;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
        .droppable-hover{background:#000;}
        .clear{clear:both;}
        </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="allshirts drop">
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb1_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb2_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb3_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb4_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb1_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb2_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb3_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb4_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb1_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb2_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb3_thumb.png" />
        <img class="shirts" src="images/tshirt_thumb4_thumb.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="blanket">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                        <td><div id="photo1" class="drop"></div></td>
                        <td><div id="photo2" class="drop"></div></td>
                        <td><div id="photo3" class="drop"></div></td>
                        <td><div id="photo4" class="drop"></div></td>
                        <td><div id="photo5" class="drop"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td><div id="photo6" class="drop"></div></td>
                        <td><div id="photo7" class="drop"></div></td>
                        <td><div id="photo8" class="drop"></div></td>
                        <td><div id="photo9" class="drop"></div></td>
                        <td><div id="photo10" class="drop"></div></td>
                </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Although that's not exactly what I am looking for, as I would still have to show which photos were used from the class="allshirts". I was hoping to remove each shirt as it was used, so each photo is not duplicated, but shown once and limited to once on the screen. I am pretty sure I can use the ($this)droppable('disable') but I know I am missing something.

Comment: To remove the image once dropped replace: $(ui.draggable).clone() with just your original ui.draggable.